# How to replace the character "F" in a huge .txt file with the return command?

Tags: windows, macos, text, replace

I have a pretty large .txt file with data (8MB) and the data lines are separated with the character F.

To analyze this data I need to replace the letter F with the Return command.

**This is how my file looks:**

```
-0.27,   -0.21,   9.56,   78.86,   47.79,   0.02F0.07,   -0.35,   9.47,   78.73,   47.74,   0.05F-0.20,   -0.43,   10.60,   79.00,   47.79,   0.07F-0.49,   -0.14,   10.44,   76.84,   47.70,   0.10.. and so on
```

**This is how it should look:**

```
-0.27,   -0.21,   9.56,   78.86,   47.79,   0.02
0.07,   -0.35,   9.47,   78.73,   47.74,   0.05
-0.20,   -0.43,   10.60,   79.00,   47.79,   0.07
-0.49,   -0.14,   10.44,   76.84,   47.70,   0.10
... and so on
```

I have a macOS and Windows available. Already tried it with Excel, but the file seems to be to large, Excel just crashes. Any advice?

Comment: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/11683)

Comment: Agree: Notepad++ then in find/replace enable 'use special character', then replace F with  \r\n (if you're on windows) or with \n if you're on *nix

Comment: I just tried it with notepad++ and the setting DDS supposed. It worked! Thanks you! Is there a way to set this question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try [EditPad Lite](https://www.editpadlite.com/download.html) on Windows. It's a notepad, that is able to handle big files.

You have to enable regular expressions (search->search options) to work correctly. After that you can open the search and replace **F** with **\r\n** (new line operator).

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS, give this a try.

Using **translate characters** command

```
tr F '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

The result will be stored in a separate file. If no new file needed, just remove `> output.txt` from the command, it will display the result in the console.

Using **stream editor** command

```
sed -i '' $'s/F/\\\n/g' test.txt
```

The `sed` command will do the same operation with the use of regex. This replace the contents in the original file. To create a backup of the file, give the extension in the argument `i` (Ex : `-i '.backup'` creates a file backup `test.txt.backup`).

For more info, do `man tr` and `man sed` in your mac terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TextEdit** on a Mac. Use the find and replace option. It is very fast in the test I tried. I used a 5 M file and it ran in a few seconds. Refer to the previous question in Ask Different 'How to use find and replace to replace a character with new line' to see how to get newlinein character in find and replace option.